# PHP comment character escaping

Tags: php, string, comments

I made a *.htaccess* file that redirects, for example, link:

**website.com/module#controller**

to:

**website.com/?url=module#controller**

As **#** is the PHP comment declarer, I get a problem when need to load:

> $bootstrap->init($url) // $url = module#controller;

I tried to use **addslashees($url);**, but still when I:

> echo $url;

I still get an output of:

**module**

How I should clear that string, to treat the **#** sign as part of the string?

Comment: What? Strings in PHP are never parsed for comments. You need to post your actual code, and some more description of what you're doing, because currently your question makes no sense

Comment: I just dont know why, the part #controller gets threated as comment. Try it yourself, with this setup: .htaccess : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] | index.php : echo $_GET['url']; | Tell me what you get, same problem or it works for you?

Comment: A `RewriteRule` won't ever see anything after the `#` mark in a URL, as the browser never sends it to the server.

Answer (score 2):

`$url = module#controller;` is not valid PHP.

`$url = 'module#controller';` will (correctly) not treat the # as a comment initiator.

Additionally, a `#` in a URL isn't going to work the way you expect. That's the marker for the URL hash/anchor, which is *not* passed to the web server. This is likely why you get output of `module` - your problem is at the browser level, not PHP.

Comment: if $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'index'; it is normal to be with quotes, but in my question it is written without, basically thinking that it is understandable that it will be 'module#controller'...

Answer (score 0):

The hashtag fragment identifier is a client-side concept only.  The browser would never send a hashtag value to the server.

If you are relying on this functionality, your are going to be disappointed as server has absolutely no way to do redirection based on the hashtag, as it never even sees the hashtag.